# How can i split a line and still keep the delimiter in linux?

Tags: linux, tr

I want to split a line based on a delimiter in linux but would still like to keep the delimiter in the first line.

For example if i try this...

```
echo ">chrAATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTAC" | tr '>chr' $'\n'
```

i am getting this output only ....

```
AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTAC
```

but what i want an output like this...

```
>chr
AATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTAC
```

Any ideas of how i can do it in linux

Comment: `tr` is not a tool for splitting input.

Comment: Is there any alternative to achieve the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try with `sed` like this:

```
echo ">chrAATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTAC" | sed 's:\(>chr\):\1\n:g'
```

where `()` creates a group that the `\1` refers to in the substitute.

Comment: Here is the ouput `>chrnAATCTAGATTTGTGTTGAACAACCCTTGGTAC`. I even tried to escape the `\n` like this `/\n` but still doesn't work

Comment: `\1\n` as it is should be sufficient given the enclosing with `'`. Copied verbatim to `bash 4.3.11` with `sed 4.2.2` works perfectly for me. You might want to try some other terminalemu/shell.

Comment: Yes it worked on a different shell. Thanks for your help!